# Creating accessible PDF(/UA) in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, accessibility

I've learnt through chance that I'm supposed to be complying with [The Public Sector Bodies (Websites and Mobile Applications) Accessibility Regulations 2018](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2018/852/made), the short version of which is supposedly that any content I put on the web needs to be accessible in a technical sense as well as a practical one. In the absence of any official guidance (I'm not sure if my organisation has noticed), I've done some searching myself and found:

- Word (we use 365 ProPlus) has a built-in accessiblity checker.
- However, a lot of what we put online are PDFs, and there is a standard called PDF/UA for accessible PDFs. Apparently we need to comply with this, this is what I meant by "in a technical sense". The recommended tool to check for compliance is [PAC3](https://support.axes4.com/hc/en-us/articles/201957988-PDF-Accessibility-Checker-PAC).
- Exporting a standard document from Word, even with `PDF/A compliant` checked in the options box, does not produce PDF/UA compliant documents according to PAC3 (indeed, PDF/A is not PDF/UA).

PAC3 has been very useful though in fixing lots of small issues like missing document titles in the metadata. But when I've done everything I can think of, it still doesn't accept the final document. Specifically, the following are flagged up:

- PDF/UA identifier is missing.
- 'Structure elements' in tables not used correctly.
- Bullet point lists can trigger an 'embedded fonts' error.
- Images apparently don't have a proper bounding box set.

Is there any standard way to produce compliant, accessible PDFs from Word (in the sense of PDF/UA), preferably without having to purchase extra enterprise-grade software? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, MS Word doesn't contain a function for creating PDF/UA files natively.

You would need additional software of some sort to create these.

I don't know if you need expensive "enterprise grade" products for this, but I, admittedly, don't have much experience trying to create this specific format, and we don't recommend software products here on Superuser. Though we have a sister site for Software Recommendations.

Comment: Microsoft Office has supported saving as a PDF since Office 2016.  It used to be the case you had to have a PDF authoring software installed. However, I suspect the problem, the file that is created simply isn't PDF/A compliant

Comment: OP differentiated between PDF/A (which Word does create) and PDF/UA, which it doesn't and which is what they need.

Comment: I swear that it originally said PDF/A...but your right Word doesn’t support it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Words implementation of a tagged PDF, which they offer inside their PDF export isn't sadly PDF/UA compliant. Many things as mentioned above and in addition several more are just wrong.

You will need another tool, which interacts with Word for writing compliant PDF/UA as a Export from Word. The onliest free one, which i know, is CIB pdf brewer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).